# Two networks and one NIC

Tags: networking

Say I have two gateways on one network. 192.168.10.* and 192.168.11.*

The domain resides on the .10 network. How could I setup my pc to hit the .11 network and if that fails then go to the .10 network.

I'd like all web traffic to flow through .11 and still be able to connect to a computer on the .10 network.

Comment: This should be moved to http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com

Comment: Would need to know a bit more about your setup, is one router or firewall the default gateway on both subnets?  Is it a web server on the .11.* range that is being connected to?

Comment: (1) Deducing from your story, your *one* network is 192.168.10.0/23 (or a greater span). (2) What domain? (3) Install a daughterboard that controls a hammer. (4) Where is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Just by the way you asked it, I am going to try to answer it to the best of my ability and with guessing on what you want.

Depends on which OS you are using. A lot of people are using Windows 7 right now so I will explain that to be nice...

1. Right click Network and click Properties
2. Click Change adapter settings in the left column
3. Right click on the adapter you want to configure and click Properties.
4. Click on Internet Protocol Version 4(TCP/IPv4)
5. Click on Properties.
6. Click Advance.
7. Add the IP addresses to the Default Gateway section in the order you want them used.

If you need anymore help, comment! :)

-Good Luck